# Can anyone help me make a Polygon Generator in Python?

Tags: python

It should ask for a number between 4 and 8 and then turtle will draw those sides.

The interior angle equation:

> where N is the # of sides (N -2)180= x, then x divided by N = draw
>   sides

```
>>> import turtle
>>> t=turtle.Pen()
>>> usernum = int(input('Give me a number between 4 and 8: '))
Give me a number between 4 and 8: 5
>>> if usernum < 4 or usernum > 8:
        print ("invalid number!")
else:
        draw
        myangle = (((numSides-2) * 180)/ numSides)
        turtle.right(180 - myangle)
```

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service... Could you demonstrate that you've at least tried _something_?

Comment: Try writing it yourself and folks here will be glad to help if you get stuck.

Comment: Wikipedia: An [equiangular polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiangular_polygon) is a polygon whose vertex angles are equal. If the lengths of the sides are also equal then it is a regular polygon. For an equiangular N-gon each angle is 180° − (360/N)°. That mean after drawing each side the turtle would have to turn that much before drawing another.

Comment: You should probably read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) if you want to stick around. Asking a lot of questions that get downvoted will eventually get you auto-banned from asking.

Answer (score 4):

Since you showed what you actually tried I'll toss you a bone, but you almost certainly could have figured out how to do this from a couple of quick Google searches.

For whatever reason I have some issues running turtle graphic scripts from IDLE, I don't know if you have better luck.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()
num_sides= int(input("Give me a number between 4 and 8: "))
side_length = 30

while True:
    if (num_sides < 4) or (num_sides > 8):
        num_sides = int(input("Invalid Number! Please enter a new one from 4-8: "))
    else:
        myangle = 360 / side_length
        break

for i in range(num_sides):
    t.forward(side_length)
    t.right(myangle)
```

If like me you have issues running that from IDLE try running it from the python interpreter in the command line.  Using a slightly modified version of this I made all of the polygons where `num_sides = range(3, 15)`.  As a note, the reason that we don't get exactly back to the start each time is due to the use of integers instead of floating point numbers. Changing this to use floating point should resolve that issue.

[image: Turtle graphics example of equiangular polygons from n = 3 to 15]